# Why doesn't this switch statement work?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I seem to forget something or do something wrong, but what? Ans what to do if I want it to say "too small" if the number is less then 1?

```
public static String doStuff(int num) {
    String number;
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
            number = "one";
            break;
        case 2:
            number = "two";
            break;
        case 3:
            number = "thee";
            break;
        case 4:
            number = "four";
            break;
        default:
            number = "Not a day";
            break;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? We can't know what's wrong if you don't tell us what isn't working and what you were expecting.

Comment: `switch` case is used for *jumping* based on matched conditions.I suggest you use a check (`if` condition) before switching to decide if a number is less than 1. Next, what do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: switch/case is defined for specific cases, but less than one is not really a case in this meaning. therfore you'd have to add a `if` statement to your default block to capture this case. `default: if (num < 1) { number ="too small";} else {number="Not a day";}`

Comment: @pramithasdhakal - Yes, you can use it from java 7. Also, he is using an int to switch not a string

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can not handle it in the switch block, but need to have a check before that like

```
 public static String doStuff(int num){
        String number;
        if (num<1) {
             return "too small";
        }
        switch(num){
        case 1:
            number= "o
```

Comment: This most certainly can be handled in the switch statement. See the other answer for how to do exactly that.

Comment: it is handled in an if block. even if the if block is put into a switch block

Answer (score 1):

Can only refer from c#
but you should do fine with something like this:

```
default:
if (num < 1)
    number= "too small";
else
    number= "Not a day";
break;
```

Comment: Yeah, totally my fault,
wrong syntax, sorry (:

got ninja-edited already :o